# Azure Devops-React project failing to build[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to devops, I have a react app that I am trying to deploy using devops. I pushed it to a repository and tries creating a pipeline using classic editor and added npm install, npm build and publish git artifacts packages respectively.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
When I try to run the pipeline I get the following error.

```
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.16
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.16" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-scripts, react-toastify)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!   react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!     react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\npm\cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-08-16T22_13_43_568Z-debug-0.log
##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Finishing: npm install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two workaround for you.

1.You could try this setting `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

2.You could try to install the appropriate node.js tool with 14.15.0
[image]